# Get all enabled shipping methods in shipping zone woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have enabled multiple shipping methods in my shipping zone.

[image]

Now, I want to get all these enabled options on my Product page.
I have found the code `WC()->shipping()->get_shipping_methods()`. But this code gives me all the shipping methods in general not those specifically in my shipping zone.

Another code is for getting chosen shipping methods is `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )` but as in admin dashboard there is no WooCommerce Session.

I want to get all these enabled options.

Answer (score 0):

update my answer here, I'm looking for the same function to get all shipping methods from Woo settings, I found this:

```
if( class_exists( 'WC_Shipping_Zones' ) ) {
    $allZones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();
}
```

From Zones, you could get shipping methods from that zones with status and detail infomation.

Hope it helps. :)